# how to decrpt url parameter in reactjs

Tags: javascript

i am getting parameter in url as p=eyJzIjoiWlIybnJVcGxVLUlGNnFZcW03cWVmUmo4MVVnIiwidiI6MSwicCI6IntcInVcIjozMDEwMTMzMixcInZcIjoxLFwidXJsXCI6XCJodHRwczpcXFwvXFxcL3Rlc3QudmFuaGV1c2VuaW5kaWEuY29tXFxcL3Jlc2V0cGFzc3dvcmRcXFwvY29udGVudFxcXC9zZWN1cmVfa2V5XFxcL2U5MmUzOWRlMDEwZmQyMTQ0ODg3NTJlODZkZTQ2NmFhXFxcL2lkX2N1c3RvbWVyXFxcLzE2OTM1ODVcXFwvc2VjXFxcLzE1OTA4MjYwMDQuNDU4XFxcL290cFxcXC8yNTgyMDE_dXRtX3NvdXJjZT1QaWdlb25fZm9yZ2V0X3Bhc3N3b3JkJnV0bV9tZWRpdW09ZW1haWwmdXRtX2NhbXBhaWduPWZvcmdldF9wYXNzd29yZFwiLFwiaWRcIjpcIjIzZGZkNDNiOGY1ODRlMmJiYTdjMzcyNGM2ZDgxMTY4XCIsXCJ1cmxfaWRzXCI6W1wiYTk4ZmEwMDgxYTk3ZjY3MGRmNDc3ZTI4MDFlYThlMzIzN2Q4YmQwMlwiXX0ifQ

Comment: What code was used to encrypt it?

Comment: It seems to be some base64 encoded JSON. Note that everyone can decode your data and see what is in, like your session id. Be careful not to leak some private data!

Answer (score 0):

What exactly can't you do? Extract the data from the URL? Convert the Base64 data to JSON? Convert JSON to data?

If your problem is simply decoding the Base64 data, you can try the *JavaScript* function `btoa()`.

EDIT (from a suggestion of Sashisu Kumar):

You can also install the `js-base64` package: `npm install --save js-base64`, then:

```js
import { Base64 } from 'js-base64';
console.log("sssdecrpt",Base64.decode(sd))
```

Comment: @Sashisu Kumar, please only edit answer to add information in it. If you want to say “thanks, it worked”, prefer adding a comment. If the (now edited) answer is the one you needed, please accept it so that the question becomes answered.

Answer (score 0):

The string shown in the example above looks like a base-64 encoded string.

The base-64 encoded string can be decoded easily using **Buffer.from()** as shown below.

**Working example of decoding base-64 data:**

```
// File name: decode-demo.js

let input = "eyJzIjoiWlIybnJVcGxVLUlGNnFZcW03cWVmUmo4MVVnIiwidiI6MSwicCI6IntcInVcIjozMDEwMTMzMixcInZcIjoxLFwidXJsXCI6XCJodHRwczpcXFwvXFxcL3Rlc3QudmFuaGV1c2VuaW5kaWEuY29tXFxcL3Jlc2V0cGFzc3dvcmRcXFwvY29udGVudFxcXC9zZWN1cmVfa2V5XFxcL2U5MmUzOWRlMDEwZmQyMTQ0ODg3NTJlODZkZTQ2NmFhXFxcL2lkX2N1c3RvbWVyXFxcLzE2OTM1ODVcXFwvc2VjXFxcLzE1OTA4MjYwMDQuNDU4XFxcL290cFxcXC8yNTgyMDE_dXRtX3NvdXJjZT1QaWdlb25fZm9yZ2V0X3Bhc3N3b3JkJnV0bV9tZWRpdW09ZW1haWwmdXRtX2NhbXBhaWduPWZvcmdldF9wYXNzd29yZFwiLFwiaWRcIjpcIjIzZGZkNDNiOGY1ODRlMmJiYTdjMzcyNGM2ZDgxMTY4XCIsXCJ1cmxfaWRzXCI6W1wiYTk4ZmEwMDgxYTk3ZjY3MGRmNDc3ZTI4MDFlYThlMzIzN2Q4YmQwMlwiXX0ifQ"
let base64Data = Buffer.from(input, 'base64')
console.log("Decoded value: \n" + (base64Data.toString()))
```

**Output:**

```
> node decode-demo.js

Decoded value:

{
    "s": "ZR2nrUplU-IF6qYqm7qefRj81Ug",
    "v": 1,
    "p": {
            "u": 30101332,
            "v": 1,
            "url": "https://test.vanheusenindia.com/....",
            "id": "23dfd43b8f584e2bba7c3724c6d81168",
            "url_ids": ["a98fa0081a97f670df477e2801ea8e3237d8bd02"]
    }
}
```

**More information:**

https://www.base64decoder.io/node-js/

https://stackabuse.com/encoding-and-decoding-base64-strings-in-node-js/